# How do I not update the Ref'ed object?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

Design:

- Entity A, B and C
- C is Ref'd in B, B is Ref'd and A
- All three are created individually
- When retrieve A, B and C are also retrieved

Problem:
 When try to save the updated A, I am getting...this error:

IOException received while updating a Sticky:400 Bad Request
                                                                                                              {
                                                                                                                "code": 400,
                                                                                                                "errors": [
                                                                                                                  {
                                                                                                                    "domain": "global",
                                                                                                                    "message": "com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: You cannot create a Key for an object with a null @Id. Object was com.example.entity_C@db12bd5 (through reference chain: com.example.entity_A[\"owner\"]->com.example.entity_B[\"myC\"])",
                                                                                                                    "reason": "badRequest"
                                                                                                                  }
                                                                                                                ],
                                                                                                                "message": "com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: You cannot create a Key for an object with a null @Id. Object was com.example.entity_C@db12bd5 (through reference chain: com.example.entity_A[\"owner\"]->com.example.entity_B[\"myC\"])"
                                                                                                              }

Comment: Cant you just declare object B as `final` and pass during A's construction?

Comment: If you were to set the reference to entity B to null before saving entity A it wouldn't update entity B. You could automate this in a `@BeforeSave` method in the entity (not a great idea but it should work). If you want to keep the reference you could replace the existing/old reference with a new one with `Ref.create(Key.create(EntityB, id))` where you could take the id from the old reference.

Comment: This question is confusing. In the title  you ask about _embedded_ objects but in the body you say it's a `Ref`, which is not embedded. Refs are just keys with get() methods - there's no cascading save or update. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: @stickfigure You are right about the question.  I changed to "Ref'd."  I am sure you are about the no cascading save or update.  In that case, it must a problem within app engine's client library.

Comment: It's not clear from the question what the problem here is. Updating one entity does not update another entity unless you do so in your code. What behavior are you seeing? It is extraordinarily unlikely that you have found a problem in GAE's client library.

Comment: @stickfigure...I updated my original question...I don't know why is it trying to create a key...it seems like the error occurs before the request is sent the endpoint.  Hope this gives you a better understanding.  Thanks!

Comment: @stickfigure...did you have a chance to review what I have done?  Any help is greatly appreciated...as always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solve the problem...apparently, I did not have the set method for my @Id field, so the client library automatically generated didn't not how to set the value at the client library end.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately Java is always pass by reference, means that any Object A = B, than you try to change B, A will change too, the only way to do this is to create new Object A = new Object(); then you copy the contents of Object B to Object A, will be something like this

```
int someInt = 5;
Object B = new Object(someInt);
```

where the constructor of class Object taking "someInt" Parameter.

```
class Object {
int j;
 Object(Int i)
{
 this.j=i;
}
int getInt() 
{
  return j;
 }
```

then you create A and equalize the content of A to the Content of B

```
  Object A = new Object(B.getInt());
```